# Chrome not displaying inline block divs correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a basic site - just html and css. Here it is: http://litlitlit.com.

I have social media icons up in the top right corner. The four icons are in a container and are displaying using `display: inline-block`.

They're displaying fine in Safari and Firefox, but are being smushed to some 12 pixel wide div in Chrome by default.

Safari and Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

When I open the developer tools in chrome, the icons display, albeit in a weird flattened way:

[image]

Here's a short fiddle of the equivalent situation: http://jsfiddle.net/5ULhN/

And here's some obligatory code that's relevant to the container / items so I can post a jsfiddle link:

```
div.menucontainer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
}
div.menuitem
{
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This is correct behaviour for what you have done. You have specified a 100% height and not a width for the images.

Comment: Have you tried setting height on .menuitem?

Comment: @Alex, what do you mean by that? that chrome is displaying the icons correctly by mushing them into the top right corner, and my code is inherently incorrect? or that chrome is actually displaying correctly for you and it's just a problem on my end?

Comment: I set the height of .menuitem to 100%. See the fiddle for how I intend it to display, and how it displays in Safari and FF.

Comment: Why cant you just set fixed dimensions for the menu items?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5ULhN/1/

Comment: The menu items are squares, but I also have the height of the header on my site set as a percentage of its parent div (body) because I'd like it to respond to the size of whatever screen it's being viewed on. So setting them to a certain size may work, but it's not ideal for what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You have the header at 100px height?

Comment: Your never going to be able to have the images 100% height, its just not logical, your best bet would be the following... http://jsfiddle.net/5ULhN/2/ Responsive and doesnt lose aspect ratio.

Comment: i'm able to have the CSS display fine in Safari and Firefox when I set the social images to 100%. Not sure what you mean by my attempts not being "logical". I've switched the height of my header to a standard 60px and it's working fine. Thanks for the input anyway, man.